# Understanding Overflow in use of Go Type Infered Const

Tags: go, overflow, type-inference

In TourOfGo const example, they write that

> An untyped constant takes the type needed by its context

But the following program throws an overflow:

```
package main

import "fmt"

const  Big  = 1 << 100 // no overflow here 
// var  Big  = 1 << 100  // overflow here 

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("big = %T",Big) // causes overflow error here
}
```

Is it the case that the overflow happens only when the const is converted to a var?

Comment: The const Big needs to be converted to a real (non const) type. Which? Big is an integer but there is no integer type large enough. The largest integer type is uint64 and Big overflows uint64. That's the error.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the literal is just a constant (not assigned anywhere), it doesn't have to be materialized, so there's no error. The compiler waits for you to actually use it somewhere. Consider this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

const  Big  = 1 << 100 // no overflow here 
    var f float64
    f = Big
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

This runs successfully and prints out a reasonable approximation of 2^100 (within the precision limitations of floats). However, if you try to assign it to a variable it will be inferred to be an int (after all, the literal is integer), and the same is true when you try to print out its type.